# How to display more listings in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, listings

I'm having an issue with the listings in the WordPress site I'm working on.

I have three listings only showing up out of 6. I can't seem to figure out how to make all of them display. This is using the twentyeleven WordPress theme.

[image]

The arrows on the right are used to move the gallery back and forth. Only one more shows up on the right side.

Here's the code I believe is generating it.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

    <?php if ( is_home() ) {
    query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3');
    }
    ?>

    <?php 

    $page_name="Articles";

    $page=get_page_by_title($page_name);

    //echo $page->ID;

    query_posts( 'cat=-1,-2' );
    ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You're explicitly excluding posts in categories 1 and 2 - are the missing three posts in those categories, by any chance?

Comment: I had a feeling that could be a part of the problem. I'll take a look and report back.

Comment: Would this be the proper code for it though? I mean based off the content I think so. I couldn't find anything regarding categories in the listing edit section.

Comment: I think, with the while loop, you should be retrieving every post - there's nothing in there to limit how many posts are returned. So all I can think is that the `query_posts()` call is responsible. Do you have access to the database? I find it a little easier to query it directly when something like this comes up.... Get the ID of one of the posts that should be showing up, but isn't, and look to see what you can find about it.

Comment: Or as a quick debugging thing - remove those IDs from the `query_posts` call to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It seems the three posts that are showing up have the same ID.

Comment: On the one hand, that does explain why there are three missing ones. On the other hand, it seems very confusing to have three posts with the same ID!

Comment: I agree, I'm just updating the website, I personally didn't build it.

Comment: Can you amend the other listings appropriately, in that case?

Comment: What I'm noticing is that when I go into to edit a listing, I have a field for a permalink and nothing that displays the link that it shows on the website... I guess more searching is needed. I'll report back when I find it.

Comment: Would this be the proper code that is generating it? I'm not entirely sure. I'm new to working with the WordPress API.

Comment: In the css it's under a slider div tag.

Comment: I'm not sure, is the short answer. If you want to check, try commenting out the whole section, and reloading the page - if the content disappears, then it's the right place.

Comment: There are 4 posts above this slider on the website. And it seems that's what this code is probably generating, plus the slider posts don't have categories like the code is saying. Not sure what is pulling this in.

Comment: Have you tried commenting things out to see if the slider disappears?

Comment: I did and nothing did. So it's being pulled in from somewhere else...

Comment: If you right-click on the slider, there should be an option to Inspect Element (at least in Firefox) - that will let you see the HTML that's generating it, so you can try and find it in the template.

Comment: div id second_content_area then its in a div tag called slider. I was able to find the css generating the styling, but that's it. The slider is showing up on the index.php page. But when I removed the code that I thought was generating it, nothing happened...

Comment: I inspected it and it appears to be a javascript issue, not php. I'll dig into it more and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Change your [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function to the following:

```
query_posts( 'cat=-1,-2&posts_per_page=6' ); // You can change the post_per_page variable as needed
```

However, I would suggest using an `$args` array instead of a querystring to make your query. The same query would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'cat'             => array( -1, -2 ),
    'posts_per_page'  => 6
);
query_posts($args);
```

It is much more readable and easier to update. Also, it's worth mentioning, you are adding a negative operator to your categories. In the `query_posts` function, that will exclude a category. You may only be getting 3 posts because you are excluding posts from your query.

Comment: I'd not realised that the `posts_per_page` setting was dependent on settings elsewhere in the configuration.

Comment: Yes, the post_per_page variable is based on the option in the admin for default post count. By setting it explicitly you can have varying post counts for each of your queries.

Comment: When I put in the second code section with and without the negatives 1 and 2. Nothing happened.